# Problem to insert data in db file with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I coded a program using Python to insert data into a SQLite database. Everything is working fine. I created a setup exe using auto-py-to-exe and the project works without problems, but when I create an installer with inno setup and try to install it on my pc, the program does not work. It can not insert the data into the database. I hope I'll have a solution for this from you!

I tried to delete the dB file that was created during the test but it doesn't always work

Comment: Do you have any logs output?

Comment: No, it just no give back message. It only no works. If I use the executable file created by using auto-py-to-exe it works perfectly!

Comment: Can I just add SQLite dll to my executable wen I build it ?

Comment: Do you have sqlite3 on your pc installed? Is the path setup correct?

Comment: Oui j'en ai installé ! Et ça marche et je l'utilise déjà !

Comment: Yes I already installed it and I often use it to storing or showing data from database.